# Can the order of Inner Joins Change the results o a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, inner-join

I have the following scenario on a SQL Server 2008 R2:

The following queries returns :

```
select * from TableA where ID = '123'; -- 1 rows
select * from TableB where ID = '123'; -- 5 rows
select * from TableC where ID = '123'; -- 0 rows
```

When joining these tables the following way, it returns 1 row

```
SELECT A.ID 
  FROM TableA A 
 INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT ID
              FROM TableB  ) AS D
  ON D.ID = A.ID
 INNER JOIN TableC C 
  ON  A.ID = C.ID 
ORDER BY A.ID
```

But, when switching the inner joins order it does not returns any row

```
SELECT A.ID 
  FROM TableA A 
 INNER JOIN TableC C 
  ON  A.ID = C.ID 
 INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT ID
              FROM TableB  ) AS D
  ON D.ID = A.ID
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Can this be possible?

Print Screen:[image]

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your results of the first query: http://rextester.com/XCKK67665  I always get back no records.  However I don't have a 2008R2 server on which to test this was 2014 Express.  Are you able to recreate this in a fiddle or on rextester?

Comment: I tested it on 2008 R2. Both queries return no rows which is what I would expect.

Comment: Since this is not possible, either you have simplified the problem out of what you showed us (since there is no where condition for instance) or you are running the two queries on different servers that have different data in the tables.

Answer (score 2):

For inner joins, the order of the join operations does not affect the query (it can affect the ordering of the rows and columns, but the same data is returned).

In this case, the result set is a subset of the Cartesian product of all the tables.  The ordering doesn't matter.

The order can and does matter for outer joins.

In your case, one of the tables is empty.  So, the Cartesian product is empty and the result set is empty.  It is that simple.

Comment: But in this case (according to the question) both queries have just inner joins, why does the first one return one row and the second one doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon mentioned, for inner joins the order of joins doesn't matter, whereas it does matter when there's at least one outer join involved; however, in your case, none of this is pertinent as you are inner joining 3 tables, one of which will return zero rows - hence all combinations will result in zero rows.

You cannot reproduce the erratic behavior with the queries as they are shown in this question since they will always return zero records. You can try it again on your end to see what you come up with, and if you do find a difference, please share it with us then.

For the future, whenever you have something like this, creating some dummy data either in the form of insert statements or in rextester or the like, you make it that much easier for someone to help you.

Best of luck.